# foreach in form not working properly

Tags: php, forms, post, foreach, get

I am a beginner in PHP so I am sorry if the answer is obvious.

Basically, I want users to click the submit button and have the id posted to aaa.php.

```
<form action='aaa.php' method='get'>`
<?php foreach ($a as $b) {
 ?>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Action" value='View' /></td>
    <td><?php echo $b['info'] ?></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $b['id']"?>
<?php echo }
echo "</tr></form></table>";
?>
```

Using the script above, it seems the foreach function make every id transferred. i.e. when using `method="get"`, I get an url of `"aaa.php?mailAction=View&id=2&id=1..."`.

How should I solve the problem?

Comment: It might help if you posted more code, or even let us know the values of `$mail` and `$a`

Comment: When you submit from a form, all the inputs in that form will be posted.

Comment: what does your `$a` variable contain? and why are you using foreach?

Comment: Hard to understand what’s actually your question/problem here. Why are you transferring multiple ID values via hidden fields anyway? Seems there’s no choice for the user to chose anything, so why not keep those values server-side in the session in the first place?

Comment: OP should `var_dump` the content of `$a`, so we know the content of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreach loop seems to work properly if you get the `id=2&id=1` in your browser query using `method=get`. I think you have to understand HTML forms first to realize your problem here.

With your code above you are generating a form with an array of ids:

```
<form action='aaa.php' method='get'>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">

  <input type="submit" name="Action" value='View'/>
</form>
```

But actually you want to send one id at a time. So you have to generate multiple forms to achieve this:

```
<form action='aaa.php' method='get'>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">

  <input type="submit" name="Action" value='View'/>
</form>

<form action='aaa.php' method='get'>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">

  <input type="submit" name="Action" value='View'/>
</form>
```

I hope, now you understand the point.

To solve your problem, your PHP code should be like so:

```
foreach ($a as $b)
{
  echo "<form action='aaa.php' method='get'>
          <input type='hidden' name='id' value=" . $b['id'] . ">
          <input type='submit' name='Action' value='View'/>
        </form>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table>
    <form action="aaa.php" method="get">
    <?php foreach ($a as $b) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Action" value="<?php echo $b['id'];?>" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $mail['info'] ?></td>            
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </form>
</table>
```

By putting the ID on submit button, you should get the value of the clicked button in the URL

Comment: Thanks! but actually I have multiple buttons on the form so the value='View' is necessary. This is my first time to post on stackoverflow and maybe I should be clearer when I post it. But I really didn't expect such a quick response! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

How about putting each id in its own form?

```
<?php foreach ($a as $b) {
 ?>
<form action='aaa.php' method='get'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Action" value='View' /></td>
        <td><?php echo $mail['info'] ?></td>
        ...
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $b['id']?>" />
      <tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the array for this type

```
<form action='aaa.php' method='get'>`
<?php foreach ($a as $b) {
 ?>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Action[]" value='View' /></td>
    <td><?php echo $b['info'] ?></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $b['id']"?>
<?php echo }
echo "</tr></form></table>";
?>
```